# Using multiple NOT IN Statements with SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, notin

I have a statement in a stored Proc that filters out certain records with a NOT IN statement before it runs an error check.

```
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (X,Y)
```

Recently a new variable was introduced that I need to filter out before one of the error check statements. What I wanted to write was.

```
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (X,Y) OR Column2 NOT IN (UD,CD)
```

This will not work though because I cannot make the second NOT IN recognize the WHERE. The `UD,CD` Keep pulling as columns instead of values within the columns. Just for information there are 7 possible values that could be in this column. and none of the nesting I have tried works right for this scenario. What am I missing? Should I approach this entirely different?

_______________________Edit_________________________________________________
Both the post from @Bjones from @briangerhards essentially solved my problem. Once I went back and looked at how the table was created I noticed that single quotes would be needed for an IN statement. In addition to this the post from @Briangerhards prompted me to look at my existing filters and I realized that the second NOT IN statement needed to be included with the first AND statement for the filter to work correctly due to the relation of the data. If I had seen the latter first on my own I may have never had posted because I had originally tried single quotes. When the filter failed I assumed they(the '') were at fault and not my structure. I suppose this should be a lesson to not panic. lol Thank you again everybody for al your assistance.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail for what you have tried and why you say it does not recognize the WHERE? This looks like it should work fine. Is UD a variable or is it a hard coded value? Can you provide the entire SQL (With masked values of course). Or provide an http://sqlfiddle.com/ example.

Comment: Try using `(` parenthesis `)` to group conditions using `OR` that combine with `AND` conditions.  Such as: `WHERE condition1=1 AND condition2=2 AND (condition3=3 or condition3=3.5)`.  In this example, you will get all rows as expected.  Remove the `(` parenthesis `)` and you'll get something different than expected.

Comment: @BrianGerhards Yes definitely I never know how much to provide in these things 'UPDATE Table1 SET Column3 = '06,' WHERE Column1 NOT IN (X,Y) OR Column2 NOT IN (UD,CD) AND (Column4 = 'Y' AND Column5 = '000000') OR (Column4 = 'Y' AND Column2= 'XX')'  The 'UD,CD' Keep pulling as columns instead of values within the columns. There are 7 possible values that could be in this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET Column3 = '06,' 
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (X,Y) 
   OR (
       Column2 NOT IN (UD,CD) 
       AND (Column4 = 'Y' AND Column5 = '000000')
       )
   OR (
       Column4 = 'Y' AND Column2= 'XX'
       )'
```

I see a few items in here that can be corrected just based on the logic. See the additional parentheses

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but it still will not work. I am thinking the problem may be on my table; because I cannot even run a simple SELECT, WHERE, IN statement against that column. I will look at it from this point of view then. Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (X,Y) AND Column2 NOT IN ('UD','CD')
```

Note the change of the single quotes as well as the AND rather than OR.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'Except' to remove the rows instead of combining two NOT operators:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName

EXCEPT

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Column1 IN (X,Y) OR Column2 IN (UD,CD)
```